# Copy value from an object to another, ignoring new properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

I have 2 objects :

```
person{
 name : string
 gender : string
}

woman{
 name : string
}
```

I have an obj "person", filled with values, and i want to copy those values in a new obj "woman", but i don't want to extend "woman" as i don't want it to have the "gender" property
I've tried with jQuery.extend(), but it adds "gender" to "woman".

How can i do?

Edit :

Actually, the full context is that in my app i have some classes representing data, with extra properties that i don't want to save. In this function, i need to "clean" those objects from those extra properties. 
I have an Interface for each class, that contains the properties that i want to save.

So i do :

```
var objInterface = <IWoman>{};
```

And then i have an empty object, and so i need to copy the person.name into my objInterface.name, and so i can serialize my objInterface with only good data.

I have many other classes than that so i need to do that dynamically

Comment: you want prop1 of obj1 in obj2, right?

Comment: @ParagBhayani yes exactly, i want value of obj1.prop1 in obj2.prop1, but i DON'T want that obj2 has a prop2  ^^

Comment: `woman.name = person.name`???

Comment: Lol yes that's a way but i have a lot of classes where i need to do the same

Comment: Why don't you provide concrete sample of your use case because otherwise you cannot find more simple like that. And you talk about class but AFAIK, there is no class concept in javascript

Comment: Ok forgot it, i didn't see you were using typescript

Answer (score 2):

```js
var obj1 = {
  prop1: 'string1',
  prop2: 'string2'
}

var obj2 = {
  prop1: 'string3'
}


Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(key) {
  if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj2[key] = obj1[key];
});
console.log(obj2);
```